# Multiple selection in Bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm looking for a proper way to implement the jquery mobile filter list in bootstrap typeahead component.

The functionality that I needed is here in the following link. Please scroll down to the bottom. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-inset.html

In the filtering list, I want to add checkboxes for each list items and the user should be able to check multiple value. They don't have to be added to the textfield. As that's the only function I need, its no use of adding the whole jquery mobile library to the project.

I found couple of options in the following link which goes near my requirement.

http://fusiongrokker.com/post/heavily-customizing-a-bootstrap-typeahead

But, the multiple selection by clicking checkboxes didn't work with bootstrap typeahead.

Can anyone give me a good solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any way to get Multiple values through Typeahead?

Comment: No @harishannam, I changed the way of implementation

Comment: I just found this today. Check this @Mujahid http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 12):

If you looking for bootstrap, this plugin can be used in your project

https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Answer (score 3):

I saw following has been suggested in many places:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

(If you use the multi-value version.)

Comment: I don't wanna mix up the jquery UI and bootstrap CSS as my application should work properly in the mobile as well. Thanks a for your solution, but I wrote a custom filtering function. Thanks again